# Google Analytics - Tracking conversions on a third party site

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

What is the current best-practice to track conversions which happen on another domain?

I have 3 affiliate links, which take users to a multi-page form on another site. The conversion happens when they reach the thank-you page.

Is a destination goal, using the URL of these sites /thank-you page appropriate. I can place a tracking pixel on these sites.

I *could* create a click event in Analytics and use that as the goal by which to measure conversions, but the user hasn't necessarily converted at that point.

Or is cross-domain tracking needed, such as:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-XX', 'auto',{'allowLinker': true });
  ga('linker:autoLink', ['theirdomain1.com', 'theirdomain2.com'], false, true);
  ga('require', 'linker');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Add the following to analytics script on partner site:

```
  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-X', 'auto',{'allowLinker': true });
  ga('require', 'linker');
  ga('linker:autoLink', ['mydomain.com'], false, true);
```

Finally, if I place a tracking pixel on the sites for the /thank-you pages, how will I know the page views originate from referrals from my domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross-domain tracking would be a better option that you will be able to see where a user gets dropped and also create a goal for this conversion.
The client-id would remain same with cross-domain tracking so you can analyze a user's full journey.